# jersey post 400: Bad Request simple register

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jersey, ejb

i have passed a lot of time to solve a simple problem using rest, but i don't way i can't post data when i test in postman or advanced rest, this is my rest resource

```
@Path("/auth")
@Stateless
public class RestWs {

    @EJB 
    private UserService userService;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void registerRest(Users u){
        Users users = new Users();
        users.setUsername(u.getUsername());
        users.setEmail(u.getEmail());
        users.setPassword(u.getUsername());
        userService.registerService(u);
    }

}
```

and this is my jpa

```
@Override
    public Users register(Users users) {
        em.persist(users);
        return users;
    }
```

and this is my entity

```
@Entity
public class Users implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Users{" + "id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + '}';
    }


}
```

i don't why i can't post data for register user , i need something else like parsing or ...., please help me, and thanks

Comment: http://localhost:8080/JersyBackEnd/resources/auth

Comment: I think your `registerRest` method is wrong

Comment: @ojuskulkarni any idea can help me and thanks

Comment: you are setting u.getUsername() or u.* ,  both the time you are using object of same class `User`that means you are setting undefined value in `user.setUsername(...)` so I think you should declare some parameters first then set it in user

Comment: What is the result you are getting? An error?

Comment: @dlcole i tested  in Advanced rest client so no specific error 400 bad request and The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Comment: You should have some kind of exception in your logs for a 400. This means it was routed correctly but some criteria is incorrect. Otherwise you would get a 404. One thing you can do is configure logging.properties for java.util.logger logger to enable debug. If you are using another logger like log4j you won't see output by default. The other thing you might want to do is to register an ExceptionMappper<Throwable> and you can print the stack trace. Jersey is throwing a WebApplicationException for the 400.

Comment: thanks @ChrisHinshaw i resolved this problem by adding CORSFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just i need to add cross filter  and all work great

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                      "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                      "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }

}
```

and in web.xml

```
<init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
          <param-value>com.ress.CORSFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

that's all